# Begginer/ numpy where and copy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to copy values from one Field2 into Field1 if Field1 is null or NaN.
I have tried below where statement as per documentation, but it cuts outliners instead of copyting the value.

`dataframe=np.where(dataframe['field1'].isnull(),np.copy(dataframe['field2']),1)`

I have interpreted it as if statement, but apparently its wrong interpretation, as results are not correct. Has anyone of you had similar issues?

[np.where source](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)  [np.copy source](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html)

Comment: `where` is not an iterator; it's a selector based on the `cond` argument.  This is python, so the arguments are evaluated in full before being passed to the `where` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `fillna` or `combine_first`:

```
dataframe['field1'] = dataframe['field1'].fillna(dataframe['field2'])

# OR

dataframe['field2'] = dataframe['fields'].combine_first(dataframe['field2'])
```

Demo:

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'field1': [1, np.NaN, 3], 'field2': [4, 5, 6]})
print(dataframe)

# Output
   field1  field2
0     1.0       4
1     NaN       5
2     3.0       6


###
dataframe['field1'] = dataframe['field1'].fillna(df['field2'])
print(dataframe)

# Output
   field1  field2
0     1.0       4
1     5.0       5
2     3.0       6
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need `np.copy`, nor `np.where`. Use pandas' [`Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) instead

```
dataframe['field1'] = dataframe['field1'].where(dataframe['field1'].isnull(),
                                                dataframe['field2'])
```

If you really want to use `np.where` the syntax is:

```
dataframe['field1'] = np.where(dataframe['field1'].isnull(), # condition
                               dataframe['field2'],          # value if True
                               dataframe['field1'])          # value if False
```